# Can uppercase type names be incompatible with the standard library?

Tags: c++, coding-style

In our project, we `PascalCase` type names and `camelCase` function names and variables. This extends to things such as `MyClass::Iterator` or `MyClass::ConstIterator` as well.

Can this be a problem when interacting with the standard library, which uses all `lower_case` names? Range based for loops for example require methods named exactly `begin` and `end`. Custom iterators should declare `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, `difference_type`, and `iterator_category` (all lower case).

Are there other cases (for example in `<algorithm>`) that require a certain naming convention to be used?

Comment: unless you're overriding stuff, I don't think this matters at all.. and usually STL is not meant to provide virtual functions or base classes

Comment: @MarcoA. The fact that custom iterators require type declarations matching certain names tells me that it certainly does matter in some cases. I'm wondering if there are any other cases beyond those I listed that programmers should beware of.

Comment: C++ is a case-sensitive language, it **does** matter.. but a "coding style convention" is how you write your code for style, readability and to work with other programmers (and that usually deals with camel case, pascal case, K&R style, etc..). Those are two different things you shouldn't confuse

Comment: I expect that "if you get it wrong, it won't compile". So having a list of all the things that you may need to adjust if the compiler doesn't compile it is pretty pointless. Of course, it's probably a good idea to not have to rewrite all references to `FooClass::Iterator` into `FooClass::iterator` when you realize you need to use `std::sort` on your `FooClass` - so having a coding standard that reduces such re-writes would be wise.